# How to expand or embed the contents of a URL in Microsoft Word?

Tags: url, hyperlink, ms-word, embed, expand

I need to create a Word document that includes information I also have on a web page. Ideally, I want to prevent duplicating the information, so would like to put the URL of the web page, and have Word "expand" the URL into the actual text from the web page.

If the Word file is opened offline, then the reader sees the contents of the web page as they were when the word file was created. 
IF the Word file is opened online, than attempt to update the contents with those that are on the web page.

Answer (score 0):

Sure its possible, but I think you'd need to write and install a VSTO AddIn (or possibly a macro) to do it.

Comment: Hi - So I guess I am looking for the addin or the macro. Any pointer?